# Unity. Две анимации одного объекта одновременно. Раскидывание по Layers не работает

Tags: unity3d, анимация

есть объект (куб) с одной и той же анимацией (размер и позиция) проигрывающейся всегда. И есть анимация которая должна добавляться при нажатии кнопки (вращение). Я сделал соответственно два слоя, во втором слое поставил один и тот же weight, blending - additive, но вторая анимация не проигрывается. Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже так пробовал, но понял так, что слои и смешивание придумали совсем для другого.

Так что лучше сделать либо отдельную суммарную анимацию и переключиться на нее, либо оставаться в первой анимации, но в процессе нее в скрипте вычислять и устанавливать rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Прописал через скрипт и все магически заработало почему-то. У меня такие параметры.

```
GetComponent<Animation>()["Passive"].layer = 1; 
GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Passive");
GetComponent<Animation>()["Passive"].weight = 0.1f;
```